# Memory de-duplication in the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, memory

Can anybody explain me the algorithm involved in Memory de-duplication in the Linux kernel 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-kernel-shared-memory/

I am finding it difficult to understand and implement it. Can anybody explain me this in simple steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you've linked appears to be fairly simple as it is.

1. Application advises kernel (using `madvise()` syscall) that certain region of its memory may contain duplicate pages.
2. `ksmd` adds the pages in this region to a "volatile list" (tree actually, for ease of later look up). "Volatile" means that the pages are still likely to change.
3. For each page in "volatile" list a checksum is computed. `ksmd` will scan all the pages in the list every now and then to see if checksum had changed. If it's indeed different every time, nothing has to be done (page is still "volatile").
4. If, after some number of scans `ksmd` notices that a checksum for some particular page stopped changing between iterations (page had "stabilized"), it can be put on a "stable" list.
5. `ksmd` will scan all existing pages in the "stable" list to see if there is a page already which matches the content of the candidate page. If such page is found, then the candidate page is discarded, and existing page from the "stable" list is mapped in its place as read only (and the associated reference count for the stable page is incremented).
6. If there are now matching pages in the "stable" list, then candidate page is marked as "read only" and moved from "volatile" list to a stable one.
7. If application tries to modify a "stable" page it will hit a "protection error" inside kernel. The error handler will invoke `ksmd` to check whether the page is on its "stable" list. If yes, it will make a writable copy of that page and tuck it back to the "volatile" list, unmapping the "stable" page from the application address space and decrementing "stable" page's reference count (if count hits 0 at this stage, the "stable" page is freed).